# SQL Server, BIG challenge, update trigger or procedure (whatever works)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have two tables

**EmpAssignment**
 EmpId | LocationNo | other errelevant

and

**MonthlyTransaction**
 EmpID | Paycode | InputAmount | and other errelevant

I would like a trigger (or whatever works) such that, if :

**1.** *EmpAssignment.LocationNo* of a certain EmpID is inserted or updated with value 104 or 105, then *MonthlyTransaction.Paycode* and *MonthlyTransaction.InputAmount* are inserted with values 35 and 12 respectively.

**2.** *EmpAssignment.LocationNO* of a certain *EmpID* is inserted, updated  with value 204 or 205 then  *MonthlyTransaction.Paycode* and *MonthlyTransaction.InputAmount* are inserted with values 36 and 15 respectively.

Now the more trick part, *MonthlyTransaction.EmpID* is a foreign key, meaning, there are more than on rows of each *EmpID*, and Insert, update should only affect an *EmpID* row with Paycode 35 or 36 and InputAmount of 12 or 15.

If there is no row of that particular *EmpID* with Paycode and InputAmount above, the trigger should insert otherwise update.

Where I got so far :

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ProvincialAllowance
ON [dbo].[Empassignment]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
UPDATE M
SET Paycode = 35, InputAmnt = 12
FROM MonthlyTransaction AS M
INNER JOIN inserted E
ON E.EmpId = M.EmpId AND E.LocationNo = 104
```

One of the issues with the above trigger, is that it will update all *MonthlyTransaction. EmpID* paycode and inputAmnt with 35 and 12

I know this is a lot to ask but please somebody save me.

Comment: Your on clause needs to handle Paycode and InputAmt as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your trigger. Using CTEs setup the conditions for Source and Target and then simple `MERGE` statement can do the rest.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ProvincialAllowance
ON [dbo].[Empassignment]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    WITH CTE_Target AS 
    (
        SELECT m.* 
        FROM MonthlyTransaction m
         INNER JOIN INSERTED e ON e.EmpID = m.EmpID
        WHERE m.PayCode IN (35,36)
         AND m.InputAmount IN (12,15)   
    )
    ,CTE_Source AS
    (
        SELECT i.empID
            ,i.LocationNo
            ,CASE WHEN i.LocationNo IN (104,105) THEN 35 ELSE 36 END AS PayCode
            ,CASE WHEN i.LocationNo IN (104,105) THEN 12 ELSE 15 END AS InputAmount
        FROM INSERTED i
        WHERE i.LocationNo  IN (104,105,204,205)
    )  
    MERGE CTE_Target t
    USING CTE_Source s
    ON s.EmpID = t.EmpID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET t.PayCode = s.PayCode, T.InputAmount = s.InputAmount
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (EmpID, PayCode,InputAmount) 
        VALUES (s.EmpID, s.PayCode, s.InputAmount);
END
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bef40/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Using first `UPDATE` and then `INSERT` all those that where not found, something like this (Only showing for Paycode = 35, InputAmnt = 12 and LocationNo = 104).

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ProvincialAllowance
ON [dbo].[Empassignment]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
UPDATE M
SET InputAmnt = 12
FROM MonthlyTransaction AS M
INNER JOIN inserted E
    ON E.EmpId = M.EmpId AND E.LocationNo = 104 AND Paycode = 35

INSERT M
SET EmpId = E.EmpID, InputAmnt = 12, Paycode = 35
FROM inserted E
LEFT JOIN MonthlyTransaction AS M
    ON E.EmpId = M.EmpId AND E.LocationNo = 104 AND Paycode = 35
WHERE M.EmpID  NULL
```

If you use SQL 2008 or above, you can use `MERGE` instead of `UPDATE` and `INSERT`